# Arraylist as argument in Interface occur NullPointer Exception in Android RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, interface

I tried to Pass String and ArrayList as an argument value through an interface from RecyclerViewAdapter to fragment, Data loading in recycler perfectly, But When I try to select the particular item in the list it leads to NullPointerException. Here is my code which is Implemented, Please help to fix my issue, I was stumbling with this issue for the whole day.

***Interface***

```js
public interface QikMsgTemplateListener {
    void onTemplateSelectedDesc(String templateId, String templateName, String templateDesc, String templateScript, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> preClipList, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> postClipList);
}
```

***RecyclerViewAdapter Class***

```js
public class QikRecTemplateAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{


private QikMsgTemplateListener mQikMsgTemplateListener;

//Constructor
public QikRecTemplateAdapter(Activity activity,QikMsgTemplateListener listener, List<TemplateModel> templateList,  String mSelectedTemplateName) {
        this.mTemplateList = templateList;
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mQikMsgTemplateListener = listener;
        this.selectedTempName = mSelectedTemplateName;
    }


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, @NonNull  int position) {

 //OnClickListener
    mHolder.mButtonTempSelect.setOnClickListener(v -> {
  TemplateModel mTemplateModel = mTemplateList.get(mPosition);
               String templateId = mTemplateModel.getTemplateId()!=null?mTemplateModel.getTemplateId():"";
                String templatename = mTemplateModel.getTemplateName()!=null? mTemplateModel.getTemplateName():"";
                String templateDesc = mTemplateModel.getTemplateDesc()!=null?mTemplateModel.getTemplateDesc():"";
                String templateScript = mTemplateModel.getTemplateScript()!=null?mTemplateModel.getTemplateScript():"";
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mSelectedPreClipList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                if(mTemplateModel.getPreClipList()!=null){
                    mSelectedPreClipList.clear();
                    mSelectedPreClipList = mTemplateModel.getPreClipList();
                }

                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mSelectedPostClipList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                if(mTemplateModel.getPostClipList()!=null){
                    mSelectedPostClipList.clear();
                    mSelectedPostClipList = mTemplateModel.getPostClipList();
                }

  /*CallBack values pass to QikRecTemplateAdapter*/
  //here facing null pointer
      if (mTemplateModel.getPreClipList() != null && mTemplateModel.getPostClipList() != null) {
                        mQikMsgTemplateListener.onTemplateSelectedDesc(templateId, templatename, templateDesc, templateScript, mSelectedPreClipList, mSelectedPostClipList);
                    } else if (mTemplateModel.getPreClipList() != null && mTemplateModel.getPostClipList() == null) {
                        mQikMsgTemplateListener.onTemplateSelectedDesc(templateId, templatename, templateDesc, templateScript, mSelectedPreClipList, null);
                    } else if (mTemplateModel.getPostClipList() == null && mTemplateModel.getPostClipList() != null) {
                        mQikMsgTemplateListener.onTemplateSelectedDesc(templateId, templatename, templateDesc, templateScript, null, mSelectedPostClipList);
                    } else if (mTemplateModel.getPostClipList() == null && mTemplateModel.getPostClipList() == null) {
                        mQikMsgTemplateListener.onTemplateSelectedDesc(templateId, templatename, templateDesc, templateScript, null, null);
                    }
    });
    }
}
```

***Fragment Class***

```js
public class TemplatesFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, QikMsgTemplateListener {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mPreClipList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mPostClipList = new ArrayList<>();
List<TemplateModel> templateList=new ArrayList<>();
@Nullable
QikRecTemplateAdapter mQikRecTemplateAdapter=null;

//All other initalitzing steps

 /*==========Invoke Lifecycle Methods==========*/
     @Override
     public void onAttach(Context context) {
  super.onAttach(context);
        if(context instanceof QikMsgTemplateListener){
      mQikMsgTemplateListener=(QikMsgTemplateListener) context;
  }else{
      throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
              + " must implement QikMsgTemplateListener");
  }
     }

 @Override
     public void onDetach() {
  super.onDetach();
  try {
      if (mQikMsgTemplateListener != null) {
          mQikMsgTemplateListener = null;
      }
  }catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
     }
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getAPIValues();
    }

 @Override
     public void onClick(@NonNull View v) {
  switch (v.getId()) {
   /*==========Action To Pass Values to Activity==========*/
    case R.id.txtVw_done_template:
   /*CallBack values pass to Activity*/
            Objects.requireNonNull(mQikMsgTemplateListener).onTemplateSelectedDesc(this.selectedTemplateId,          this.temp_name,this.selectedTemplateDesc,this.selectedTemplateScript,this.mPreClipList,this.mPostClipList);
          Fragment mPresentDoneFragment=this;
          try {
              Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mPresentDoneFragment).commit();
          }catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}finally {
              mPresentDoneFragment=null;
          }
          break;
      default:
          break;
  }
     }
 @Override
     public void onTemplateSelectedDesc(String templateId, String templateName, String templateDesc, String templateScript,
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> argPreClipList, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> argPostClipList) {
  try {
      if (!templateId.isEmpty()) {
          this.temp_name = templateName;
          this.selectedTemplateId = templateId;
          this.selectedTemplateDesc = templateDesc;
          this.selectedTemplateScript = templateScript;
   /*Here Values comes Empty or 0 when i put try catch in AdapterClass*/
          if(argPreClipList!=null){
              this.mPreClipList = argPreClipList;
          }
          if(argPostClipList!=null){
              this.mPostClipList = argPostClipList;
          }
         }
  }catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
     }




void getAPIValues(){
  JSONObject mResponseObj=null;
                //ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mPreClipList = new ArrayList<>();
                //ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mPostClipList = new ArrayList<>();
                boolean hasHeader=false;
                boolean hasFooter=false;
                boolean canPostComments=false;
                boolean canTakeSurvey=false;
                boolean doNotAutoPublish=false;
                boolean doNotArchive=false;
                try {
                    templateList.clear();
                    mResponseObj=new JSONObject(getResponse);
                    try {
                        String str_json_status = mResponseObj.optString(AppResponseTags.TAG_JSON_STATUS);
                        if (str_json_status.equalsIgnoreCase(AppResponseTags.TAG_RESPONSE_SUCCESS)) {
                            JSONObject clientResponse_obj = mResponseObj.optJSONObject(AppResponseTags.TAG_CLIENTRESPONSE);
                            String str_totalRecords = clientResponse_obj.optString(AppResponseTags.TAG_TOTALRECORDS);
                            JSONArray templateContent = clientResponse_obj.optJSONArray(AppResponseTags.TAG_DATA);
                            try {
                                if (!clientResponse_obj.isNull(AppResponseTags.TAG_DATA))
                                    for (int templateCount = 0; templateCount < templateContent.length(); templateCount++) {
                                        JSONObject templateContent_Obj = templateContent.optJSONObject(templateCount);
                                        try {
                                            if (!templateContent_Obj.isNull(AppResponseTags.TAG_ID)) {
                                                str_templateId = templateContent_Obj.optString(AppResponseTags.TAG_ID);
                                            } else {
                                                str_templateId = "";
                                            }
                                            if (!templateContent_Obj.isNull(AppResponseTags.TAG_NAME)) {
                                                str_templateName = templateContent_Obj.optString(AppResponseTags.TAG_NAME);
                                            } else {
                                                str_templateName = "";
                                            }
                                            if (!templateContent_Obj.isNull(AppResponseTags.TAG_PRESIGNEDTHUMBNAILURL)) {
                                                str_templateImage = templateContent_Obj.optString(AppResponseTags.TAG_PRESIGNEDTHUMBNAILURL);
                                            } else {
                                                str_templateImage = "";
                                            }
                                           

                                            if(!templateContent_Obj.isNull(AppResponseTags.TAG_DESCRIPTION)){
                                                description=templateContent_Obj.optString(AppResponseTags.TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                                            }else{
                                                description="";
                                            }

                                            if(!templateContent_Obj.isNull(AppResponseTags.TAG_SCRIPT)){
                                                scriptTxt=templateContent_Obj.optString(AppResponseTags.TAG_SCRIPT);
                                            }else{
                                                scriptTxt="";
                                            }
                                             
                                                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mTempPreClipList = new ArrayList<>();
                                                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mTempPostClipList = new ArrayList<>();
                                                if(!templateContent_Obj.isNull(AppResponseTags.TAG_PRECLIPS)) {
                                                    JSONArray mPreClipArray =new JSONArray();
                                                    mPreClipArray = templateContent_Obj.optJSONArray(AppResponseTags.TAG_PRECLIPS);
                                                    try {
                                                        if (mPreClipArray != null && mPreClipArray.length() > 0) {
                                                            try {
                                                                System.out.println("*-------------------*********--------------------------*");
                                                                for (int i = 0; i < mPreClipArray.length(); i++) {
                                                                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                                                                    try {
                                                                        JSONObject dataObject = mPreClipArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                                                        String mPreContenId = dataObject.getString(AppResponseTags.TAG_CONTENTID);
                                                                        map.put("preclipid", mPreContenId);
                                                                        mTempPreClipList.add(map);
                                                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                                                    }finally {
                                                                        map=null;
                                                                    }
                                                                    System.out.println(str_templateName+"->"+"Array-Pos-PreClip-"+i);
                                                                }
                                                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                                ex.printStackTrace();
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                                    } finally {
                                                        //mPreClipList = null;
                                                        mPreClipArray = null;
                                                    }
                                                    System.out.println("*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*");
                                                    System.out.println(str_templateName+"->"+"Array-Pos-PreClip Array-" + mTempPreClipList.size());
                                                    System.out.println("*---------------------========================--------------------------*");
                                                }

                                                if(!templateContent_Obj.isNull(AppResponseTags.TAG_POSTCLIPS)) {
                                                    JSONArray mPostClipArray =new JSONArray();
                                                    mPostClipArray = templateContent_Obj.getJSONArray(AppResponseTags.TAG_POSTCLIPS);
                                                    try {
                                                        if (mPostClipArray != null && mPostClipArray.length() > 0) {
                                                            try {

                                                                for (int i = 0; i < mPostClipArray.length(); i++) {
                                                                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                                                                    JSONObject dataObject = mPostClipArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                                                    try {
                                                                        String mPostContenId = dataObject.getString(AppResponseTags.TAG_CONTENTID);
                                                                        map.put("postclipid", mPostContenId);
                                                                       mTempPostClipList.add(map);
                                                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                                                    }finally {
                                                                        map=null;
                                                                    }
                                                                    System.out.println(str_templateName+"->"+"Array-Pos-PostClip-"+i);
                                                                }
                                                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                                ex.printStackTrace();
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                                    } finally {
                                                        //mPostClipList = null;
                                                        mPostClipArray = null;
                                                    }
                                                    System.out.println("*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*");
                                                    System.out.println(str_templateName+"->"+"Array-Pos-PostClip Array-" + mTempPostClipList.size());
                                                    System.out.println("*---------------------========================--------------------------*");
                                                }
                                                
                                                    templateList.add(new TemplateModel(str_templateId, str_templateName, str_templateImage, temp_name,description,scriptTxt,mCallToActionType,mCallToActionLink,mCallToActionText,mAuthorEmailSignature, hasHeader, hasFooter, canPostComments, canTakeSurvey, doNotAutoPublish, doNotArchive, mChannelList,mTempPreClipList,mTempPostClipList));
                                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                ex.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                               
                                    if (templateList.size() > 0) {
                                       
                                            mQikRecTemplateAdapter = new QikRecTemplateAdapter(getActivityContext, templateList, this, temp_name);
                                        
                                        rcyVw_ChooseTemplate.setAdapter(mQikRecTemplateAdapter);
                                        rcyVw_ChooseTemplate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        rcyVw_ChooseTemplate.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                                       
                                    }
                                
                                
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
}


}
```

***StackTrace***

```js
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.ibot.cyranoapp.interfaces.quickmessage.QikMsgTemplateListener.onTemplateSelectedDesc(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference
W/System.err:     at com.ibot.cyranoapp.adapters.quickrecord.QikRecTemplateAdapter.lambda$onBindViewHolder$0(QikRecTemplateAdapter.java:279)
W/System.err:     at com.ibot.cyranoapp.adapters.quickrecord.-$$Lambda$QikRecTemplateAdapter$oPCYWC6_gHETxZtfdm5pQwAQTow.onClick(lambda)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:130)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

In this code I added comment for better explanation about my issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Add the stacktrace too ..

Comment: where are you getting the null

Comment: Sorry, I added my stack trace just now.

Comment: Add the code for init the adapter in your fragment

Comment: Can you run it step-by-step ? It would seem from the stacktrace that `mQikMsgTemplateListener` is null when reaching your `onBindViewHolder` function, can you check that ?

Comment: @Mwak Yes, data loading in recycler perfectly, But When I try to select the particular item in the list it leads to the crash.

Comment: where did you declare and create `QikRecTemplateAdapter`?

Comment: @Tommy I missed to add into this post, now I added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mismatched the parameters when initiating your adapter. Your listener should be the second paramter

Comment: Indeed ! Here's the code as is : `mQikRecTemplateAdapter = new QikRecTemplateAdapter(getActivityContext, templateList, this, temp_name);`

And as it should be :  `mQikRecTemplateAdapter = new QikRecTemplateAdapter(getActivityContext, this, templateList, temp_name);`

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: @ronginat No still issue is happening

Answer (score 2):

I think your listener is not getting initialized properly, and therefore it's throwing `NullPointerException`.

Try creating a setter for your listener and initialize on your TemplatesFragment's  onCreateView() method:

```
public class QikRecTemplateAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

    private QikMsgTemplateListener mQikMsgTemplateListener;

    public void setQikMsgTemplateListener(QikMsgTemplateListener listener){
       mQikMsgTemplateListener = listener;
    }
    ...
    ...
}


public class TemplatesFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, QikMsgTemplateListener {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mPreClipList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mPostClipList = new ArrayList<>();

        ....

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        //Initialize adapter before setting the listener.
        qikRecTemplateAdapter.setQikMsgTemplateListener(this)
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
      if(qikRecTemplateAdapter != null)
        qikRecTemplateAdapter.setQikMsgTemplateListener(null)

      super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

Also, to avoid `NullPointerException`, always place a null safety check wherever you use it.

Comment: No still issue is happening.

Comment: Then try to debug the code and find out the cause, otherwise, this is the best I can figure out with the details you provided.